# runOnFirstFix not actually running on first location fix

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview

When using a mapView, runOnFirstFix throws a null pointer exception because `MyLocOverlay.getMyLocation()` is null. However, this should not happen becuase runOnFirstFix should not run when the location is null. What's going on here?

```
myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    map.getController().animateTo(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());                
}
```

I'm using the emulator to run this code so maybe it's an emulator problem?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into this API, but why don't you wrap that call in an if block that checks if the location is null?

```
if (myLocOverlay.getMyLocation() != null) {
  myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    map.getController().animateTo(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());                
  }
}
```

And more importantly, if you are using the emulator, you need to make sure that you are feeding the emulator gps fixes from the DDMS perspective, this tutorial explains how:

[You Are Here: Using GPS and Google Maps in Android](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39239/1954)

Comment: I know I can just check if it's null or not. But it _shouldn't_ be `null` because the runnable should execute when it's not `null`. I was more interested in why it's behaving the way it is, not a solution. Thanks for the information though.

Comment: how are you giving the emulator locations?

Comment: I am manually setting the coordinates through the Emulator Control view in Eclipse.